# Showing that the operator is bounded and find its norm.

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, normed-spaces, lp-spaces

I have this operator $T: L^p(0,\infty)\rightarrow L^p(0,\infty)$, $1<p<\infty$ :

$$(Tf)(x)=1/x\int_0^xf(t)dt.$$

I am supposed to show that it is bounded and fint its norm. I had an idea that almost worked for showing that it was bounded, but then I ran into a problem. And also I do not see how to show that its norm is $q$, where $q$ is given by $1/p+1/q=1$.

First we have:

$|(Tf)(x)|\le1/x\int_{[0,x]}|f|dt=1/x\int_{[0,x]}|f|\cdot1dt$, and then by Hölder:

$$\le1/x(\int_{[0,x]}|f|^pdt)^{1/p}(\int_{[0,x]}1^gdt)^{1/q}\le \|f\|_px^{-1+1/q}=\|f\|_p/x^{1/p}.$$
But this function is not in $L^p(0,\infty)$. And showing that the norm is $q$, I really don't know how to do.

Do you guys have any tips?

Comment: Where did your $1/x$ in the very first line of the computation come from?

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry there as a little typo in the second line.

Comment: A big typo you mean ;)

Comment: @Tryss Hehe, yeah, sorry.

Comment: Is it also a little typo that you said $x^{-1/p} = x^{-p}$? You need to take a bit more care.

Comment: @TedShifrin No, that wasn't a typo, but a mistake.

Comment: Have you tried using the closed graph theorem? It is pretty useful when proving boundedness of an linear operator. To find the bound you need ti work harder. My suggestion is to try integration by parts

Comment: One further comment: $T$ is supposed to map to $L^p$, so you need to compute the $L^p$ norm of $T(f)$, not the $C^0$ norm.

Comment: @TheOscillator Yeah I tried that, but I ended up just reducing the problem to showing that T had to be bounded. Using closed graph I get that If $f_n \rightarrow f$, and $Tf_n \rightarrow g$, I must show that $Tf=g$, but I have:$\|Tf-g\|_p\le\|Tf-Tf_n\|_p+\|Tf_n-g\|_p=\|T(f-f_n)\|_p+\|Tf_n-g\|_p$ The last part goes to zero by assumption, but proving that the first part goes to zero, is essentially proving continuity at 0, hence everywhere(since L is linear).

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, that I understand, maybe we are not working with functions that are even bounded. But we have $[1/x^{1/p}]^p=1/x$, which is not integrable, therefore $1/x^{1/p}$ is not in $L^p$.

Comment: True, but you need $\int_0^\infty \frac 1{x^p}\left|\int_0^x f(t)\,dt\right|^p\,dx$ to exist, don't you?

Comment: @TedShifrin Yes, I agree with that. Are you saying that it may noe exist? I assume it exists because else that exercise wouldn't make sense.

Comment: @TedShifrin I found the exercise online here: http://www.mathematik.uni-muenchen.de/~lerdos/WS04/FA/Week4.pdf it is the last one. In the exercise it is said that it is an operator from $L^2(0,\infty)$ to $L^2(0,\infty)$, and by that, the norm of any  function-value(which you wrote to the power of p) should be finite.

Answer (score 3):

Since continuous functions with compact support obviously belongs to $\mathcal{L}^{p}(0,\infty)$, we shall first solve the problem for that class of functions and then try to finish it of by a standard density-argument. So suppose $f$ is non-negative as well. Then it is pretty straightforward to prove by the fundamental theorem of calculus that $$\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+} T(f)(x)=\lim_{x\rightarrow 0+}\frac{1}{x}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\, dt=f(0+)$$ and that the operator is well-defined for every other $x>0$. Now an integration by parts gives that $$||T(f)||_{p}^{p}= x\cdot T(f)(x)^{p} \,|_{0}^{\infty} +p\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(T(f)(x)^{p} -T(f)(x)^{p-1}f(x)\right) \, dx= $$ $$p\cdot ||T(f)||_{p}^{p} -p\int_{0}^{\infty}T(f)(x)^{p-1}f(x) \, dx$$

Collecting the terms involving $||T(f)||_{p}^{p}$ and dividing and using Hölders inequality we get $$||T(f)||_{p}^{p}= \frac{p}{p-1}\int_{0}^{\infty}T(f)(x)^{p-1}f(x)\, dx\leq \frac{p}{p-1}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}T(f)(x)^{(p-1)q}\, dx\right)^{1/q}\cdot ||f||_{p}=$$ $$\frac{p}{p-1}\left(\int_{0}^{\infty}T(f)(x)^{p}\, dx\right)^{1/q}\cdot ||f||_{p}= \frac{p}{p-1}\cdot ||T(f)||_{p}^{\frac{p}{q}}\cdot ||f||_{p}$$ where $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}=1$. Now assuming $||T(f)||_{p}$ is non-zero otherwise the claim is trivial, we divide and obtain  $$||T(f)||_{p} \leq \frac{p}{p-1}\cdot ||f||_{p.}$$ for every non-negative continuous function $f$ with compact support.

Now using the simple fact that $|T(f)(x)| \leq T(|f|)(x)$ for each $x\in (0,\infty)$,the result immediately extends to all continuous functions with compact support on $(0,\infty)$. Now to finish off the proof, let $g$ be an arbitrary $\mathcal{L}^{p}(0,\infty)$ and $\left\{f_{n}\right\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$ a sequence of continuous functions with compact support that converges to $f$ in $\mathcal{L}^{p}$-norm. We can extract a subsequence $\left\{f_{n_{j}}\right\}_{j=1}^{\infty}$ which converges to $g$ almost everywhere on $(0,\infty)$.

Now using Fatou's lemma, we finally get that $$||T(g)||_{p}\leq \liminf_{j\rightarrow \infty} \, ||T(f_{n_{j}})||_{p}\leq \liminf_{j\rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{p}{p-1}||f_{n_{j}}||_{p}\leq \limsup_{j\rightarrow \infty} \, \frac{p}{p-1}\left(||f_{n_{j}}-g||_{p} +||g||_{p}\right)= \frac{p}{p-1}||g||_{p}$$

Comment: Are you missing an exponent of $p$ in the first part of the integration by parts, i.e. should it be 'an integration by parts gives that $\|T(f)\|_p^p=x\cdot T(f)(x)^p |_0^\infty$'? If not, how are you getting that? My guess was that we're doing int by parts on $T(f)(x)^p$ and $x$.

Comment: Also, how can I see that the limit $f(0+)$ exist?

Comment: @ciru_4011 Yes, you are right, there was an exponent $p$ missing there. Note that I'm only claiming that the limit $f(0+)$ exists for continuous compactly supported functions $f$ in $\mathcal{L}^p(0,\infty)$